# Apache mod_rewrite help, send folder to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make my .htaccess file do this:

> ```
> From: http://www.domain.com/example  
> -OR-  http://domain.com/example  
> To:   http://example.domain.com
> ```

and

> ```
> From: http://www.domain.com/example/newfolder/file.html?q=blank  
> -OR-  http://domain.com/example/newfolder/file.html?q=blank  
> To:   http://example.domain.com/newfolder/file.html?q=blank
> ```

For the life of me, I have searched and searched, and just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/.*)?$ http://$1.example.com$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: would this go in root or the example subdirectory?

Comment: @Theo: This is intended to be used in the .htaccess file in your document root directory. But don’t forget the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`.